# PRAW Subreddit model works fine for a few requests - and then only sends 503 errors for a while

Tags: python, python-3.x, praw, reddit

As the title suggests, I run this once a day and it works fine for the first few requests and then it seems to randomly stop working and will then only serve 503 errors.

This has only been a recent problem, the code has been working fine for the past two months. Has anyone else experienced this? Below is a snippet of where the error happens:

```
# create reddit object
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id = client_id,
                     client_secret = client_secret,
                     user_agent = user_agent)

# use PRAW subreddit model
sub = reddit.subreddit('economy')

sub_list = []

try:
    for s in sub.submissions(start = start_date, end = end_date):
        sub_list.append(s)
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

Answer (score 1):

HTTP 503 code means that the service is not available. This is an error on Reddit's side. You should catch the exception and utilize a retry strategy such as [exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Reddit actually posted an update that their search has been slightly broken as of late so this will continue to happen until it's fixed.